# Ubuntu gives a purple screen while booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, lightdm

I have ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 10. It gives the purple ubuntu screen on start up. If I go to the recovery mode and then resume from there, I go on to the login page where it gets into a login loop. I tried multiple ways but couldn't resolve the issue.

I think I messed up with the nvidia drivers or lightdm I tried re-configuring lightdm but didn't help I also tried moving the .Xauthority file into another file but it did not help

Comment: I have had this too.

Comment: You know of any solution? I have important files on my pc

Comment: Please post the output of dpkg -l | grep "nvidia*"

Comment: And what is your graphics care model?

Comment: Do I run it in recovery mode as root?

Comment: Yes you do. The second last one from the bottom and type your password.

Comment: How do I post the output? I mean I can't access my pc. I can upload a screenshot though

Comment: Yes do that, that would be great.

Comment: Or a pic of your screen.

Comment: Can't upload a pic in comments

Comment: Upload to something or another and give me a link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1uPITiZ51pVDNsbGtrZkZ5dkE/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Like Dropbox or google drive. I can't access Imgur or Flickr here.

Comment: And what's your model card number?

Comment: That's all I need to formulate a answer,

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1uPITiZ51pUE1pZ0RHRENERk0/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: No access avaliable.

Comment: l https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-1uPITiZ51pUE1pZ0RHRENERk0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
apt purge nvidia-3*
apt install nvidia-352
update-initramfs -u
```